# Proof of the uniqueness of the solution of the problem: $v=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The proof of the uniqueness of the solution of the problem

$$\Delta u=f, \text{ at } D$$
$$u=h, \text{ at } \partial{D}$$

is the following:

Let $u_1, u_2$ solution of the problem above.

$v=u_1-u_2$

$$\Delta v=0, \text{ at } D$$
$$v=0, \text{ at } \partial{D}$$
$v$ is a harmonic function, so it has its maximum and minimum at the boundary.

From the maximum principle, $v=0$.

My question is:

Do we conclude that $v=0$, because of the fact that $v$ has its maximum and its minimum at the boundary and both, the maximum and the minimum are equal to $0$, so the function $v$ is a constant and its value is $0$?

Comment: Yes: max=min, so that the function is constant.

Comment: Ok!!! Thank you!!! :-)